# Defined variable changes value, if original value changes

Tags: java, for-loop, reference

I have this piece of Java code

```
private static void move(int[] brd) {
    int[] brd_orig = brd;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(brd_orig)); //Print brd_orig
    for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
         for(int j = 1; j < 12; j++) {
             int c = brd[i];  //Swap brd[i] and brd[j]
             brd[i] = brd[j]; //Swap brd[i] and brd[j]
             brd[j] = c;      //Swap brd[i] and brd[j]
         }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(brd_orig)); //Print brd_orig
}
```

My intention is to save the parameter `brd` for a later usage in `brd_orig` by this line `int[] brd_orig = brd;`.

Now I am changing `brd`, but not `brd_orig` inside the second for loop. So my expected result is that `brd_orig` never changes the value. I use the prints at the beginning and at the end to prove it, but it behaves not as expected.

When I run the function by

```
move(new int[]{0, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 2});
```

the **real** output is

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1]
```

but the **expected** output is

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

I was able to locate the responsible lines

```
int c = brd[i];
brd[i] = brd[j];
brd[j] = c;
```

When I remove them, the error is gone, but I never change `brd_orig`.

I think it could maybe be *pass-by-reference* or *pass-by-value* error.

**Why is this code not behaving as expected?**

Comment: You need to make a copy of the 2D array.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your answer. Which 2D array do you mean? brd and brd_orig are 1D arrays, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, arrays identifiers point to the location, not the values themselves. So `int[] brd_orig = brd;` means "point `brd_orig`, an `int[]`, to the same location as `brd`", so they are different identifiers for the same array. You can use [`.clone()` or `System.arraycopy()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-copy-in-java/) to make a duplicate array.

Comment: Ah, I see. A common pointer problem. Thank you :)